# Permutations with a fixed element

Tags: group-theory, permutations

How would you understand the following set of permutations

$$S' :=\{ \pi\in S_n\mid \pi(n)=n\}$$

is the subset of all the permutations that fix the $n$-element?

Is it simply $S_{n-1}$? For example, consider $S_3$, then the subset contains all the permutation that fix the $3$. So the $S'=\{ (213) \}$?

Comment: We have $S' \cong S_{n-1}$, but in your example $S'$ also contains the identity element.

Comment: Your notation would usually be understood to mean a $3$-cycle that does *not* fix $3$.  Most people would read your notation as the permutation that sends $2$ to $1$, $1$ to $3$, and $3$ to $2$.  The usual cycle notation for the non-identity element of $S'$ in your example is just $(1~2)$.

Comment: Thanks. The notation I used is not the cycle rather the element that results from the transformation on the ID element caused by the cycle. However, it this set equal the S(n-1)?

Answer (score 1):

The fixed points of a function $f$ are precisely those elements $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)=x$. Since each permutation is a function and your set $S'$ is, by definition, the set of all permutations $\pi$ such that $\pi(n)=n$ (and $S'$ contains no other elements), it follows that $S'$ is precisely the set of all permutations that fix that $n$ element.

Note that $S'\cong S_{n-1}$.

By the way, your example is mistaken. Note that $(213)\notin S'$ when $n=3$ because it does not fix $3$; it sends $3$ to $2$.

Comment: Thanks. So π(n) =n implies that only the last element n is to be fixed? Regarding the example it shows one element of the set S3 with last element fixed. The ID element is included

Comment: You're welcome, @Thomas. No. For example, when $n=4$, the permutation $(12)$ fixes both $3$ and $4$, but since $(12)$ evaluated at $4$ is $4$, we have $(12)\in S'$.

Comment: I have updated my answer, @Thomas. If it is satisfactory, please accept it.